# Is it possible to pass a variable variable when including Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use a Django template to create links to unchosen releases in a dropdown button.

The created links are defined like this:

```django
{% for release in all_releases %}
  {% if release != in_release and release != out_release %}
    <a href="{% url url_view %}?in_release={{release}}&out_release= {{out_release}}">{{release}}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

and

```django
{% for release in all_releases %}
  {% if release != in_release and release != out_release %}
    <a href="{% url url_view %}?in_release={{in_release}}&out_release={{release}}">{{release}}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Would it be possible to create `dropdown-link.html` file containing:

```django
{% for release in all_releases %}
  {% if release != in_release and release != out_release %}
    <a href="{% url url_view %}?in_release={{in_release_query}}&out_release={{out_release_query}}">{{release}}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

and to invoke it in the actual rendered template like this, sort of creating variable variables:

```django
{% include "release-dropdown.html" with in_release_query=release out_release_query=out_release %}
...
{% include "release-dropdown.html" with in_release_query=in_release out_release_query=release %}
```

I know this exact approach is not possible here. Would you recommend an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags):

You can create a tag that takes two arguments and renders `release-dropdown.html`

```py
@register.inclusion_tag('release-dropdown.html')
def release_dropdown(in_release, out_release):
    return {
        'in_release': in_release,
        'out_release': out_release,
    }
```

then invoke it in your template with variables:

```py
{{ load '<name of the template tag file>' }}
{% release_dropdown release out_release %}
```